# Understanding the last algebra step of this proof

Tags: graphs, probabilistic-algorithms

Could someone help me understand why in the below proof, if $k > log_{2}n$, then $P(N_i=1)< \frac{1}{n}$?
[image]

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: OK, will do so in the future, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @FlyingSpaghetti please edit your question to provide a link to the source, and mention where your proof is located in the source.

Comment: @FlyingSpaghetti i offer an upvote to your question upon transcription of the text and mathematics.

Comment: @FlyingSpaghetti use descriptive title as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't read the whole proof, but you don't seem to be having any problem with the previous statement that $\Pr(N_i = 1) = \frac{1}{2^k}$.  Then, using the fact that $2^x$ is an increasing function,  the identity $2^{\log_2 x} = x$, and $k > \log_2 n$:
$$
\Pr(N_i = 1) = \frac{1}{2^k} < \frac{1}{2^{\log_2 n}} = \frac{1}{n}.
$$